# How do I create a fixed footer whilst still using a flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project for University, and I'm trying to create a fixed footer whilst using a flexbox layout. I've tried adjusting all kinds of heights and widths, played with the margins and overflow options but I just can't get the footer to act as if I'd changed the display options. Where am I going wrong?

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.maincontent {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

.social {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-social-icons {
  padding: 5px;
}

.searchbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.brands {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <title>Streetworn</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="maincontent">
      <p>content to fill this box</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="social">
        <ul class="nav-social-icons">
          <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="#" alt="Follow Streetworn on Twitter!" height="35px"></a>
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="#" alt="Follow Streetworn on Facebook!" height="35px"></a>
          <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><img src="#" alt="Follow Streetworn on Instagram!" height="35px"></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="searchbar">
        <p>Text to fill this area</p>
      </div>
      <div class="brands">
        <p>Text to fill this area</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to make it so that the main content will be able to scroll up and down whilst the footer sits on the bottom of the page. Please teach me how to sort this out, I've been staring at it for the past 4 days and I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: The images are centered in the footer just fine, by the way. The images aren't linked on here so it looks worse than it actually is.

Comment: Take your footer out of the flex flow -- let the footer exist on its own and use `position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; ... `

Comment: Would that not mess up the formatting of the 3 sections within the footer though?

Comment: Nope, not necessarily -- check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvdtgag/ using your code all I did was add in position fixed and it works (I also bumped up the size of the main content to demo the fixed footer)  However, with this approach, you want to make sure that you don't end up leaving content that could be hidden by the footer and not accessed.

Comment: And one can add `height: auto` to show the full height of the footer.

Comment: Okay it's looking good so far, but the the footer now goes above the scrollbar on the side, is there an easy fix to that or is it really convoluted? Thanks by the way guys. Is there a way to adjust the height of the scrollbar on the page?

Comment: You could style the scrollbar and give it a width. Reduce this width in the footer width with calc: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvdtgag/7/ . It's a little bit hacky. :-)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid (there menu MUST have `li` as children).

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'll have what I want with a tweak here and there!

Answer (score 1):

Your container wants to be flex then you can add flex grow to your content:

```css
body {margin:0;}
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  /* put flex on this container */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.maincontent {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  
  /* grow the content */
  flex-grow:1;
}

footer {
  margin: auto;
  height: 80px;               /* this is now optional */
  width:100%;
  background-color: #ff6600;
  overflow:hidden;            /* I added this as you icons were coming out of the bottom */
}

                              /* not touched anything below here */
.social {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-social-icons {
  padding: 5px;
}

.searchbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.brands {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="maincontent">
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
    <p>content to fill this box</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="social">
      <ul class="nav-social-icons">
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="#" alt="Follow Streetworn on Twitter!" height="35px"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="#" alt="Follow Streetworn on Facebook!" height="35px"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><img src="#" alt="Follow Streetworn on Instagram!" height="35px"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="searchbar">
      <p>Text to fill this area</p>
    </div>
    <div class="brands">
      <p>Text to fill this area</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```